# Making Npcs talk using Papyrus - Skyrim Modding

Tags: game-development, papyrus-script

I'm trying to make npcs talk using Papyrus Actor.Say function.

I created a simple mod for that. I created a quest and in that, created a reference alias and bound it to an npc (Faendal or Lucan Valerius). Then I created a topic in that quest and recorded my voice and saw that the wav file replaced in the correct location. Finally, I created a script and in a loop, every 5 seconds, I call .Say function from that Npc reference.

Debug shows that the code is running and the .say function is called. But I couldn't make the npcs say anything.

I tried with Faendal who is busy carrying logs. So I thought this maybe an issue (a package is playing) and tried with Lucan Valerius. After the initial scene with his wife ended, I expected that he might say my line, but I can't make him speak either.

Here is my Papyrus code:

```
Scriptname npcSayLineScript extends Quest

ReferenceAlias property NpcRef auto 
Topic property NpcSayLineTopic auto 

Event OnInit()
    `Debug.Trace("Initialized NpcSayLine")`
    
    `While True`
        `If NpcRef != None`
            `NpcRef.GetActorReference().Say(NpcSayLineTopic)`
            `Debug.Trace("NpcSayLine: Saying line - " + NpcRef.GetActorReference().GetDisplayName())`
            `Utility.Wait(5)`
        `EndIf`
    `EndWhile`
EndEvent
```

Do you have any idea what might be the issue here? The properties of the script are correctly configured and there are not exceptions thrown.